# Removing duplicate JSON objects from file

Tags: python

I have a json file from which I am trying to remove duplicate Json objects. Provided below is a sample of this file and my approach.

```
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:39:11 GMT", "title": "Goat Goat"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:39:11 GMT", "title": "Goat Goat"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:24:15 GMT", "title": "Cat cat"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:19:29 GMT", "title": "Chicken Chicken"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:19:29 GMT", "title": "Chicken Chicken"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 10:50:15 GMT", "title": "Dog Dog"}
{"published": "Tue, 03 Mar 2015 10:34:45 GMT", "title": "Cat cat"}
```

My approach was to create a script by initialising an empty list, reading each line (object) in the file to check for unique titles and writing the unique objects into a new json file.

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file, output_file  = argv

input_file = open(input_file)

output_file = open(output_file, 'a')

unique = []

while True:
    A = input_file.readline()
    if A['title'] not in unique:
        unique.append(A['title'])
        output_file.write(A)
```

However, I'm getting the below error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_run.py", line 13, in <module>
    if A['title'] not in unique:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

New to python so would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: You should actually parse out the json from the file.  You're just reading lines and indexing then as if they were json objects which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the title as a key in a `dict` object and use the fact that dictionary keys are a set:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
with open('your_json.json') as f:
    # load json objects to dictionaries
    jsons = map(json.loads, f)

uniques = {x['title']: x for x in jsons}

# write to new json file
with open('new_file.json' ,'w') as nf:
    json.dump(uniques.values(), nf)

print uniques.values()
```

Or you can use `json` and `set` for this in a more straightforward way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
with open('your_json.json') as f:
    # load json objects to dictionaries
    jsons = map(json.loads, f)

result = list()
items_set = set()

for js in jsons:
    # only add unseen items (referring to 'title' as key)
    if not js['title'] in items_set:
        # mark as seen
        items_set.add(js['title'])
        # add to results
        result.append(js)

# write to new json file
with open('new_file.json' ,'w') as nf:
    json.dump(result, nf)

print result
```

Output:

```
[{u'title': u'Goat Goat', u'published': u'Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:39:11 GMT'}, {u'title': u'Cat cat', u'published': u'Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:24:15 GMT'}, {u'title': u'Chicken Chicken', u'published': u'Tue, 03 Mar 2015 11:19:29 GMT'}, {u'title': u'Dog Dog', u'published': u'Tue, 03 Mar 2015 10:50:15 GMT'}]
```

**note**: This will serialize the list as a list, not line after line like your original file. To do that you can use:

```
# write to new json file
with open('new_file.json' ,'w') as nf:
    for js in uniques.values():
        nf.write(json.dumps(js))
        nf.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the json library. Instead of simply reading the file, use:

```
import json

with open(input_file, 'r') as infile:
    A = json.load(infile)
```

That should solve this problem. However, your code has some more issues.

Why are you using `while True`? This will never terminate, and instead throw an exception when your input_file has no more lines.

Instead, you can simply convert your list to a set, which guarantees uniqueness. Note, that this will give uniqueness of all fields, not just title. Do that as follows: `unique = set(A)`

Finally, you will have to use the json library to write it to your output file:

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```